# C# Datatable Compute on Index instead of Name?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using a Datatable in ASP.NET / C# and would like to use the Compute method to sum each column, is there a way of doing this based on column index rather than column name so I can just place it in a for loop along the lines of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text = dt.Compute("SUM(i)", "").ToString();
        }
```

It's not overly critical to my application as I will be using an array of the column names elsewhere so I can use that array to construct the SUM with the name.

Comment: not sure if you can SUM directly by index. Could you instead use `"SUM(" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + ")"` ?

Comment: @paolo you should post that as an answer. It doesn't look like indices are supported so your suggestion is what I was about to post.

Comment: @Ahmad MattP's question was if SUM by index is supported, so if you have found evidence that they it is not go ahead and post your answer. Feel free to reuse the suggestion from my comment, I don't mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like expressions used by [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) support referring to columns by index. In fact, the MSDN documentation for the [DataColumn.Expression property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) emphasizes the use of column names:

> When you create an expression, use the
>   ColumnName property to refer to
>   columns.

You could use the [`ColumnName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname.aspx) in your loop to refer to the current column's name, as [@paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497364/) suggested in the comments to your question. This would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string expression = "SUM(" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + ")";
    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text = dt.Compute(expression, "").ToString();
}
```

Comment: What if the column name is numeric?

Comment: @D-Jones have you tried the approach above? The `ColumnName` property always returns a string, so even if the actual name is a number, the type will be a string like `"42"`, so I imagine it would still work.

Comment: The compute method still has a hard time understanding. This is out of the scope of this question, but what I did is qualified the name with braces, i.e. "SUM([0])"